# R list character removal

Tags: regex, r, string

lst1 is a list:

```
lst1 <- list(c("all the apples", "apples in the tables", "fashion prosthetics"),  c("meteorological concepts", "effects of climate change", "environmental"))
```

I want to preserve the list structure and remove the last s from all the words. The desired answer is the list below:

```
> lst1
[[1]]
[1] "all the apple"      "apple in the table" "nature"            

[[2]]
[1] "meteorological concept"   "effect of climate change"
[3] "environmental"
```

I tried

```
gsub("\\'s|s$|s[[:space:]]{0}","",lst1)
```

but it is not preserving the list structure.

How can it be done?

Comment: Can you update with some examples where the current gsub fails

Comment: Can you try this `gsub("\\'s|s$|s\\b", '', 'fashions')#
[1] "fashion"`

Comment: please see the policy on self-vandalization: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106807/how-should-we-treat-posts-that-are-vandalized-by-their-original-authors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with `lapply` to loop over the list elements

```
lapply(lst1, gsub, pattern= "\\'s|s$|s\\b", replacement='')
#[[1]]
#[1] "all the apple"       "apple  in the table" "fashion prosthetic" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "meteorological concept"    "effect  of climate change"
#[3] "environmental"
```

Comment: there is a problem in this answer. If there is a word fashion, it is becoming fa hion. Only the last s in every word must be removed, not other s

Comment: @john I thought your `gsub` pattern is correct, (didn't test it) and you only want it to apply over the list

Comment: @john I got `fashion prosthetic `

Comment: now the last s is getting removed, but a space is taking its place. "prosthetics" is becoming "prosthetic ". The space must not be there

Comment: @john It is easy `lapply(lst1, function(x) gsub('\\s+$', '', gsub("\\'s|s$|s\\b", ' ', x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Same solution, different regex, using a non-capturing group to leave whitespace as is:

```
> lapply(lst1, gsub, pattern="s(?= |$)", replacement="", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "all the apple"      "apple in the table" "fashion prosthetic"

[[2]]
[1] "meteorological concept"   "effect of climate change" "environmental"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler regex:

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) gsub('s\\b', '', x))
```

Results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "all the apple"      "apple in the table" "fashion prosthetic"

[[2]]
[1] "meteorological concept"   "effect of climate change"
[3] "environmental"
```

Comment: Personal preference for me. I saw the others, just wanted to save keystrokes.